# Adding active state to lists that expands in Vuetify.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, user-interface, vuetify.js

just as I said in the title above, how can I add a active state for lists in Vuetify? I want to apply a primary background just as they did in there docs:

[image: Sidebar active state]

My code:

```html
<template>
  <v-navigation-drawer width="300px" :clipped="$vuetify.breakpoint.lgAndUp" app>
    <v-list nav expand>
      <v-list-group
        v-for="(item, i) in items"
        :key="i"
        no-action
        color="primary"
      >
        <template v-slot:activator>
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </template>

        <v-list-item
          v-for="(subItem, i) in item.children"
          :key="i"
          @click="$router.push(subItem.path)"
        >
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title v-text="subItem.title"></v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list-group>
    </v-list>
  </v-navigation-drawer>
</template>

<script>
import SidebarLinks from '@theme/components/SidebarLinks.vue'
import NavLinks from '@theme/components/NavLinks.vue'

export default {
  name: 'Sidebar',

  components: { SidebarLinks, NavLinks },

  props: ['items']
}
</script>
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It described in [Lists documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lists/). For example in the [Dense](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lists/#dense) section.

`item` shows which item from `items` list is active.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    item: 1,
    items: [
      { text: 'Real-Time', icon: 'mdi-clock' },
      { text: 'Audience', icon: 'mdi-account' },
      { text: 'Conversions', icon: 'mdi-flag' },
    ],
  }),
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card
      class="mx-auto"
      max-width="300"
      tile
    >
      <v-list dense>
        <v-subheader>REPORTS</v-subheader>
        <v-list-item-group v-model="item" color="primary">
          <v-list-item
            v-for="(item, i) in items"
            :key="i"
          >
            <v-list-item-icon>
              <v-icon v-text="item.icon"></v-icon>
            </v-list-item-icon>
            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title v-text="item.text"></v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list-item-group>
      </v-list>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```